# Animating from display none using JS Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying animating an element which has display property set to null. Objective is to recreate something that bootstrap does in modal.

Further Explanation:
An element which is set to display none on page load but when a user clicks a certain button it shows up with animation (fade in for example). Then when user click on close button or that button again it fades out and its display property is set to none again.

Problem:
When box display property is set to none. And i click on the button. It's display is set to block and adding class "Show" both occur simultaneously and instantaneously so element just shows rather than animating

Here is my Code:

## HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="box" class="show">

</div>
```

## CSS:

```
#box {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease all 0.3s;
}

#box.show {
    transition: ease all 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;      
}
```

## Javascript:

```
var box = document.querySelector("#box");
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
box.style.display = "none"
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(box.style.display == "none") {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      box.style.display = "block";
      resolve();
    }).then(function() {
      box.classList.add('show');
    });
  } else if(box.style.display == "block") {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      box.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        box.style.display = "none";
      })
      resolve();
    }).then(function() {
      box.classList.remove('show');
    });
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptLggbmb/1/

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that. Just updated the question. Here's the problem ->

When box display property is set to none. And i click on the button. It's display is set to block and adding class "Show" both occur simultaneously and instantaneously so element just shows rather than animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Promises you could simply use the `transitionend` listener and for the fadeIn animation force a layout/reflow before applying the class to the box.

```js
var box = document.querySelector("#box");
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var prevDisplay = box.style.display;
  var listener = function() {
    box.style.display = "none";
    removeListener(listener);
  };
  if (prevDisplay !== "none") {
    addListener(listener);
    box.classList.remove('show');  
  } else {
    removeListener(listener);
    box.style.display = null;
    box.offsetLeft;
    box.classList.add('show');
  }

  function addListener(fn) {
    box.addEventListener('transitionend', fn);
  }

  function removeListener(fn) {
    box.removeEventListener('transitionend', fn);
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}

#box.show {
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="box" class="show">

</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated this to the extreme, IMHO. Try this (Pure CSS with a simple JS toggle of classes):

https://jsfiddle.net/ptLggbmb/17/

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="box" class="show">
```

**CSS:**

```
  #box {
   background-color: aquamarine;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;
   transition: ease all 1s;
 }

 #box.show {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;   
 }
```

**JS:**

```
 var box = document.querySelector("#box");
 var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
 btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   box.classList.toggle('show');
 });
```